# Add data from a textView to an accessible database

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am a beginner at Xcode, and I am trying to make a suggestion box app. However, I don't know how to make it so that when someone adds text into my textView and presses submit, the text from the textView saves and is shown somewhere else in the app. To make it more clear,
1. The user adds text into the texView(needed to use textView because I need multiple lines) 2. When the user presses submit, the text from the textView saves inside a database. 3. I can see whatever is inside that database.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a database built to handle this request already?

Comment: What have you done so far in terms of research? You can use CoreData to persist the suggestions made by your users.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I have figured it out. Because it is a suggestion box app, I used a parse database, which is accessible to anyone who has the app.